# Divide in a Linq to SQL query

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

How can I form a Linq to sql Query for this code in SQL, I tried several things. This is my basic code:

```
List<Movie> movies =
(from item in db.Movies select item).ToList<Movie>();
return movies;
```

This is what I want as a result.

```
select (Won/Total) as 'rankPercentage'
from dbo.Filmranking
order by rankPercentage desc
```

Thanks

Comment: FilmRanking looks like it is a separate table. How is it connected to the Movies table?

Comment: You can assume that the fields in the table are "id","name","won","total". It is the intention to divide two columns and make a new column for it, like in SQL. Is this possible in ASP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var movies =
    (from items in db.Movies
    select new { RankPercentage = item.Won / item.Total })
    .ToList();
```

At this point, movies will be a `List<T>` where T is a float or int depending on the underlying SQL type (which I cannot discern from your question). If you really want to project this back as a `List<Movie>`, you will need to project that as follows but your result is not likely to match your SQL table.

```
List<OtherMovieType> movies = 
    (from items in db.Movies 
     select new OtherMovieType() {
         Name = item.Name,
         RankPercentage = item.Won / item.Total
         })
       .ToList();
```

Comment: andleer, please right me if I'm wrong, but I thought you cannot project the same entity type from the context you are retrieving from, I think you will have a referencing issue plus a context out of sync, at least that was my impression.

Comment: I stated that in my answer. "f you really want to project this back as a List<Movie>, you will need to project that as follows but your result is not likely to match your SQL table". Will update the code to better point that out.

Answer (score 0):

You need something called projection, something like this:

```
var result = db.Movies
             .Select(x => new { title=x.Title, rank = (x.Won/x.Total) })
             .OrderBy(x => x.rank);
```

***EDIT*** Maybe you want the title to identify your records :)

Answer (score 0):

```
item.Won / db.Awards.Count
```

Is count a property? I think it is.

Comment: Or maybe it's x.Count() and x.Length is the property.

Comment: Does 1 / 2 return .5 or an integer?